# Unity: How to load scene from iOS native app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I've been following the tutorial:
https://the-nerd.be/2014/08/07/call-methods-on-unity3d-straight-from-your-objective-c-code/
But I'm having some issue when it comes to switch scene.
When i call method :

```
[self callUnityObject:"dummy" Method:"ChangeScene" Parameter:"scene2"];

UnitySendMessage(object, method, parameter);
```

My project crashed app, and show warning in consol output:

> Unloading 2 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 2)

What can I do? Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using unity version < 5, you are okey, so I dont know the problem, if you are using version > 5, there is a new way to change scenes. Read more [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1109497/unity-53-how-to-load-current-level.html)

Comment: Can you post the c# code of script on `dummy` which has `ChangeScene` method